# c++ libgen.h (mingw) missing for vc140 x64 project - helper functions

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, mingw, c++14

I have these helper functions:

```
std::string
pathname_directory(const std::string &pathname)
{
  char buffer[pathname.size() + 1];
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  std::copy(pathname.begin(), pathname.end(), buffer);
  return std::string(dirname(buffer));
}

std::string
pathname_sans_directory(const std::string &pathname)
{
  char buffer[pathname.size() + 1];
  memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
  std::copy(pathname.begin(), pathname.end(), buffer);
  return std::string(basename(buffer));
}
```

which rely on libgen.h, a mingw header.

1) Why does VS give the error "expression must have constant value" for the lines containing "char buffer[pathname.size() + 1];"?

2) Are there any pre-defined functions to handle this for VS 2015?

Comment: microsoft visual studios compiler 2015 (called 2014 for some reason)?

Comment: You are mistaken. Microsoft Visual Studio 2015's compiler's version number is 14. There's no year in there at all.

Comment: editted to vc140 (the official compiler abbreviation) plus x64 as it wasn't stated. Is that more helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libgen.h` is [Posix header](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/libgen.h.html),
so the question has no particular connection with `mingw`.

The compiler complains about:

```
char buffer[pathname.size() + 1];
```

because Standard C++ (any standard) prohibits variable length arrays (although
C99 permits them).

You could avoid using VLAs by rewriting your functions:

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <libgen.h>

std::string
pathname_directory(const std::string &pathname)
{
    char const *cs = pathname.c_str();
    std::size_t cslen = pathname.size() + 1;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> pbuf(new char[cslen]);
    std::copy(cs,cs + cslen,pbuf.get());
    return dirname(pbuf.get());
}

std::string
pathname_sans_directory(const std::string &pathname)
{
    char const *cs = pathname.c_str();
    std::size_t cslen = pathname.size() + 1;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> pbuf(new char[cslen]);
    std::copy(cs,cs + cslen,pbuf.get());
    return basename(pbuf.get());
}
```

However, the help that you get from `dirname` and `basename` is perhaps
not worth the rigmarole of getting it like this (or indeed in the way you
were trying to get it).

Especially so if what you want of `pathname_directory(pathname)`
is all of `pathname` up to but not including the last path-separator,
and what you want of `pathname_sans_directory(pathname)` is all of `pathname`
after the last path-separator. Because `dirname` and `basename`
will then surprise you by returning "." in cases where you expect the empty string.
See the [`dirname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/dirname.html)
and [`basename`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/basename.html)
documentation.

If that's so, the course of least bother would be Do It Yourself:

```
#include <string>

std::string
pathname_directory(const std::string &pathname)
{
    std::size_t len = pathname.find_last_of("/\\");
    return len == std::string::npos ? "": pathname.substr(0,len);
}

std::string
pathname_sans_directory(const std::string &pathname)
{
    std::size_t len = pathname.find_last_of("/\\");
    return len == std::string::npos ? pathname : pathname.substr(len + 1);
}
```

Comment: looks good, i'll implement it later and see the result. thanks :)

Comment: this worked but there were other issues relating to the build, I have started a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242467/csiro-face-analysis-sdk-linux-to-windows-conversion

Answer (score -1):

or you can compile with LLVM(clang) on Windows. You can install clang as part of the Visual Studio install under C++. Clang allows variable-length arrays , but the MSBuild (the default in Visual Studio) does not.